# Python Sklearn doesn't work anymore in eclipse IDE

Tags: python, eclipse, scikit-learn

I updated Sklearn package:

```
sudo pip install -U numpy scipy scikit-learn
```

in mac osx 10.8 (mountain lion), and, aparently, everything was fine. I tested it via terminal (command line) and it works. But the package stop working in my IDE eclipse(juno). I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/marceloschiessl/RDF_text_project/tese/testDevelop.py", line 9, in <module>
    import datetime, nltk
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 103, in <module>
    from nltk.collocations import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/collocations.py", line 39, in <module>
    from nltk.metrics import ContingencyMeasures, BigramAssocMeasures, TrigramAssocMeasures
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/metrics/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from nltk.metrics.scores import          (accuracy, precision, recall, f_measure,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/metrics/scores.py", line 16, in <module>
    from scipy.stats.stats import betai
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py", line 334, in <module>
    from .stats import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py", line 181, in <module>
    import scipy.special as special
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy/special/__init__.py", line 546, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import *
  File "numpy.pxd", line 155, in init scipy.special._ufuncs (scipy/special/_ufuncs.c:21818)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

Any help?

Comment: Uninstall/reinstall numpy, reinstall nltk too. Otherwise just install the anaconda distribution.

Comment: @elyase, I didn't get why should I have to reinstall. As I mentioned, it works when I use python via command line in terminal. I concluded that my python setup is working, the problem is with the IDE, don't you think?

Comment: Oh I didn't read that. You are right, the IDE and the terminal are using different pythons. You can find about this in the terminal using `which python` and checking in your IDE preferences if its is the same path being used.

Answer (score 0):

I use PyDev so I'm reporting you about "good practice" related to this plug-in. Every time you update your python packages is highly suggested to update your "Python interpreter" PYTHONPATH. To do so go to:

Windows -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreters -> Python Interpreter

In that place you can use the "Quick Auto-Config" button or review and correct the PYTHONPATH by hand.

HTH